# cocos2d js 3.7 runScene issue

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

So i am porting my game from cocos2d c++ to js and sorted lots of js related differences already, but can not understand nor find online the solution to particular problem involving switching of the scenes with the cc.director.runScene().

So i have a complex game scene which i load like that:

```
cc.LoaderScene.preload(gameplay_resources, function () {

    cc.director.runScene(new GameScene(level, epoch));
}, this);
```

Which takes stage and level params and returns the scene object which contains all the gameplay elements.

Fragment of Game scene looks like this:

```
var GameNode = cc.Node.extend({
levelID:null,
epoch:null,
platforms:null,
boardSize:null,
numberOfMovesLeft:null,
numberOfMovesAllowed:null,
sessionInfo:null,
ctor:function (levelID, epochID)
{
    this._super();

    this.levelID = levelID;
    this.setEpoch(Epoch.epochForNumber(epochID));
    this.platforms = [];

    var self = this;

    var gameplayUI = ccs.load(gameplayRes.GameplayUI, "res/");
    this.addChild(gameplayUI.node);

    var replayButton = gameplayUI.node.getChildByName("replay");
    cc.assert(cc.sys.isObjectValid(replayButton), "Replay button not valid");
    replayButton.addTouchEventListener(function (sender, type) {

        if(type != ccui.Widget.TOUCH_ENDED) return;

        cc.LoaderScene.preload(gameplay_resources, function () {

            cc.director.runScene(new GameScene(self.levelID, self.epoch.ID));
        }, this);

    }, this);

    return true;
}

    //... Other methods

});

var GameScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    ctor:function (levelID, epochID) {
        this._super();
        var gameNode = new GameNode(levelID, epochID);
        this.addChild(gameNode);
    }
});
```

All works fine in the end in the scene itself, but say if i change the scene by the same method to main menu, and then go to gameplay again, it seems as the 'new' game scene object has previous (supposed to be released) object`s values. So if i press 'Replay' button, it uses the old game scenes values as well.

I mean in C++ when you replace scenes, old scene`s memory is released by cocos engine. And if you go to that scene by creating new object - its new.

So my question is why is that happening i js? Maybe i do not know something about cocos2d js memory management so i need to do something extra to release old scene?

What i have ensured:

- When i extend the engines classes all my added variables a null'ed and objects values are assigned in ctor's using this.value = ...; not to have static values for all objects in that way.
- There are no children retaining the Gameplay scene (or it seems not to be) so i am assuming it should be released when i replace scene?
- I am not using retain()/release(), and all children are added to the gamescene to be retained.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: If you no longer have a question, please delete this one. SO isn't a discussion forum. If you have a solution that's useful to the community, post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So i have solved it - i was using event manager therefore sending events and game scene with its children have been registered for some of them. I was assuming that eventManager retains nodes on a 'weak' basis, but it seems you have to call removeListeners() for each registered node in its onExit method to remove listeners manually. So now it seems to be working fine.